# load an aspx page having reportviewer in a div in another page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Reportviewer aspx code is given below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class PresentationLayer_Reports_ReportViewer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Details.rdlc");

        spGetDetails_Report dsCustomers1 = GetData("spGetDetails_Report");
        ReportDataSource datasource1 = new ReportDataSource("spGetDetails_Report", dsCustomers1.Tables[0]);
        ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource1);
        ReportViewer.ShowPrintButton = true;
        ReportViewer.AsyncRendering = false;           
    }
}

public spGetDetails_Report GetData(string query)
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {               
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CId", 1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PStartDate", "2010/10/01");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PEndDate", "2011/05/05");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SId", 0);


                using (spGetDetails_Report dsCustomers = new 
spGetDetails_Report())
            {
                sda.Fill(dsCustomers, "spGetDetails_Report");
                return dsCustomers;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in another page I used the below to call the ReportViewer.aspx, but the viewer is loading no data showing and the toolbar is disabled also

```
jQuery("#ReportContainer").load(('ReportViewer.aspx'));
```

in another page I used the below to call the ReportViewer.aspx, but the viewer is loading no data showing and the toolbar is disabled also

Comment: Could you please add what you have tried?

Comment: to load aspx report in div you need to first convert your report into pdf and than load into iframe.

Comment: Please check the post.I have updated with the required details.